# How to select all SessionID in cmd (Wthout Administrator's SessionID)

Tags: remote-desktop, batch, cmd.exe, session

I can show the active SessionID with the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4" %a in ('"query session | find "Active""') do echo %b
```

While I can show disconnected SessionID changing the searched word (from "Active" to "Disc").

How can I find both active and disconnected SessionID excluding the administrator SessionID?

Comment: You can get sessionname from `query` for active connections than filter it with `tasklist /FI "USERNAME ne administrator" /FI  "SESSIONNAME eq XXX"` where is XXX active sessions you got from `query`?

Comment: Could you be more precise? I have multiple remote sessions that I will have to kill! Infact I need to extract all SessionID (of active and disconnected sessions) 
from query without Administrator's SessionID

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstand, you want to kill rdp sessions except administrator... You can get session name for admin only first with `query session administrator` and save admin's ID   then in a loop filter sessions from `query session` result, that start with `rdp-tcp` from column SESSIONNAME  and compare column ID with saved, if it doesn't match then `reset ID` to kill other rdp sessions.

Comment: yes, but how can I isolate activated and disconnected sessionid? If i can store it in only one variable, after i can kill them with do reset session %b

Comment: `query session` returning in column STATE status of connection, you can parse result by both columns SESSIONNAME & STATE and combine match by AND in IF statement inside loop